# Why is there no padding although I set it when using flexbox with `space-between` in react native?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

**The Problem:**

I have created a simple Header Component which uses this styling (`styled-components`):

```
const HeaderContainer = styled.SafeAreaView`
  padding: 25px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;
```

But when I put 2 children inside of it they have 0 padding.

[image]

So you might ask now, why don't you just use margin instead of padding?

In one screen I have to place a Textfield in exactly the middle of the screen (with `margin: auto`)

But when I do this it's not exactly in the middle:

[image]

Here is the full relevant code for this problem:

The `Header` Container:

```
const HeaderContainer = styled.SafeAreaView`
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const Header = ({children}) => <HeaderContainer>{children}</HeaderContainer>;
```

And here is the relevant part where the Text is not centered:

```
const LabelText = styled.Text`
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
`;

const NewgameScreen = ({navigation}) => (
  <Container>
    <Header>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} size={35} color={'white'} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <LabelText>Neues Spiel</LabelText>
    </Header>
  </Container>
);
```

## Last but not least. A codesandbox example with react (without native but same problem there): https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-mestorf-f9495?fontsize=14

**So how to best handle this scenario?**

Comment: please share enough of the html and the css to reproduce your issue so we see where the padding is applied, where boundaries of each element is and so on .. *usually this is enough to show you where it goes wrong and you end up without posting any question while you may find out a typo or your mistake, if you do , then the question is clearer*

Comment: Thx for your comment @G-Cyr 
I edited the post with 2 examples that show how I do it. Also:
* I want to have 3 items in the Header for the most part (with space-between)
* I But in this screen I want to just have 2 with the 2nd Element exactly in the center

Comment: are on the screen shot, yhe black areas the mobile itself,may ii got confused from the screenshot. inline elemnt will only be abble to apply padding on the horizontal unless the parent is a flex or grid box . , here i see flex alignement rules but the display:flex rule is missing to triggerit

Comment: I think you might have overlooked that I'm using `react-native` here. React native is flexbox only. And yes the black area is the border from the iphone Simulator.
So padding is not possible with flex? How can I solve this problem where I want to center 1 element in the flex container exactly in the middle?

Comment: padding is possible , there is no reason why it should not be applied to a not inline element

Comment: So any ideas? :D

Comment: maybe , putting an example online https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6 would help understand what's happening there.

Comment: I have created a sandbox where you can see the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-mestorf-f9495?fontsize=14

Comment: okay, `p` on `margin : auto` , is in the middle of the room unused by icone , you can set icone in absolute position to remove it from the flow or add another element after p, of the same width of icone, to balance size occupied on both sides of the element(p) you want to center . https://codesandbox.io/s/great-perlman-mf9dh (there is plenty duplicates under the flex tag about this)

Comment: Thx man. But what about that: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-mestorf-f9495?fontsize=14
It also has to stame inside of the container and should be vertically aligned.

Comment: `<p style={{ position: "absolute" , marginTop: "auto" , marginBottom:"auto"}}>Icon</p>` take care.

Comment: In the code sandbox example it works but not on the iOS version. Here is how it looks right now with all your settings: https://imgur.com/a/DDIuMP6
For no I solved it by adding a third icon with same size and setting the color to `transparent` but is this a clean solution?

Comment: you could use a pseudo ::after with the same width as icon to do the job instead a transparent icone. a padding-right (or margin)  could also be used to fake the room used by the extra icone.